# Spend a second thinking about 2cd vs 2nd

Tags: word-choice, grammar, slang

I've seen both 2cd and 2nd used during my life, sometimes almost interchangeably, and so I started wondering; what is the difference and what is the correct usage?

Comment: I've never seen ***2cd*** used instead of ***2nd***. Can you give any examples (from native speakers/writers)?

Comment: Likewise.  Are you certain the 2cd wasn't a typo, or if written, poor penmanship?  Also, I question this being on-topic for this site.

Comment: @cobaltduck spelling is on-topic. elementary spelling by checking a dictionary is on-topic by 'please cite your prior research'

Comment: I could understand it as an abbreviation of *secundus* perhaps. Perhaps. Maybe perhaps. But I've definitely never seen it.

Comment: I get around the problem by simply saying "tooth".

Answer (score 2):

I can find examples of *2cd* as an abbreviation for the ordinal number *second*, but they are so rare that I would take them to be typographical errors, rather than legitimate uses. Google Books, for example, turns up an example in the *[Journals of the [South Carolina] House of Representatives 1785–1786](https://books.google.com/books?id=JPrvAAAAMAAJ&dq=%222cd%22&q=%222cd%22)*, where the House Rules are enumerated:

[image: "2cd. Every Member who does not attend…"]

But for this *one* instance of *2cd*, there are at least *twenty-nine* pages where *2nd* appears— and it appears in no other edition of this series.

A commoner convention seems to have been to use *d* for both *second* and *third*, as in *22d of November* or *2d Epistle of Paul to the Corinthians*, and I found [at least one](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZlxBAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA24-IA2&lpg=PA24-IA2&dq=%22Charles%20IInd%22) example of *IInd*. But I do not think you will find much acceptance of *2cd* for *2nd* in most circles.

Answer (score 0):

I believe 2cd might be used (rarely) as an abbreviation for "seconded" in notes of board meetings. It is not correct as an abbreviation for the ordinal "second" (in other words, most readers would be confused by that usage).